# Cannot get only digit with linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get only the digit part inside my string that is:

```
Hello World 5
```

so the result must be: `5`

What I did is:

```
var temp = from c in "Hello World 5"
           select c
           where Char.IsDigit(c);
```

but I get an error on `c`, the compiler need a `;` but I don't understand why, the query isn't over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is `from`-`where`-`select`, so you should **reorder `where` and `select`**:

```
var temp = from c in "Hello World 5" where Char.IsDigit(c) select c;
```

This produces in the `csharp` interactive shell:

```
csharp> var temp = from c in "Hello World 5" where Char.IsDigit(c) select c;
csharp> temp
{ '5' }
```

This is thus an `IEnumerable<Char>`:

```
csharp> temp.GetType();
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Char]
```

You can also use equivalent function calls, in which case `select` is not necessary:

```
var temp = "Hello World 5".Where(Char.IsDigit);
```

**EDIT**: in case you want the join the results of the LINQ query together to a string, you can use `String.Concat`:

```
csharp> String.Concat("Hello World 5".Where(Char.IsDigit)); 
"5"
csharp> String.Concat(from c in "Hello World 5" where Char.IsDigit(c) select c);
"5"
```

Comment: @MarioSerda: what result did you expect?

Comment: I need to extract 5

Comment: So you want the first match? Or a string containing all matches?

Comment: Just the number 5, so removing "Hello World" :)

Comment: @MarioSerda: but do you want a `char`, or a `string`?

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, the `select` belongs at the end:

```
var temp = from c in "Hello World 5"
           where Char.IsDigit(c)
           select c;
```

Since you moved `select` at the wrong position, the compiler expected a `;` before the (then also unexpected) `where`.

---

Note that `temp` is not a single character, but a sequence containing the single element `'5'`.